# Descending cells for excel spreadsheet using macro VB

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

this is my first post in here... can you please help me out with this code I have.. now the code is for two buttons I've created on my Excel Spreadsheet for work.. and as you can see it creates a new Spreadsheet and moves the results to it into two columns (which is fine) I just need the information (on the result sheet) to be Ascending or Descending (assuming its the same thing but only the word differs). thanks a million in advance ;) cheers.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim DueDate, CurrentDate As Date
Dim ReadDays, j, k, LastRow, DaysDiff As Integer
Dim ResultSheet, CurrentSheet As Worksheet

j = 4
k = 1
LastRow = 4
CurrentDate = Date
ReadDays = InputBox(Prompt:="Set alarm for how many days?", Title:="Alarm Input Box", 

Default:="Number of days")

While ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1).Value <> ""
LastRow = LastRow + 1
Wend

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet()
Set ResultSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, ActiveSheet())

While j < LastRow
If (IsDate(CurrentSheet.Cells(j, 16))) Then
DueDate = CurrentSheet.Cells(j, 16)
If (DaysDiff <= ReadDays) Then
ResultSheet.Cells(k, 1) = CurrentSheet.Cells(j, 1)
ResultSheet.Cells(k, 2) = CurrentSheet.Cells(j, 16)
k = k + 1
End If
End If
j = j + 1
Wend

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim DueDate, CurrentDate As Date
Dim ReadDays, i, k, LastRow, DaysDiff As Integer
Dim ResultSheet, CurrentSheet As Worksheet

i = 4
k = 1
LastRow = 4
CurrentDate = Date
ReadDays = InputBox(Prompt:="Set alarm for how many days?", Title:="Alarm Input Box", 

Default:="Number of days")

While ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1).Value <> ""
LastRow = LastRow + 1
Wend

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet()
Set ResultSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, ActiveSheet())

While i < LastRow
If (IsDate(CurrentSheet.Cells(i, 14))) Then
DueDate = CurrentSheet.Cells(i, 14)
DaysDiff = DateDiff("d", CurrentDate, DueDate)
If (DaysDiff <= ReadDays) Then
ResultSheet.Cells(k, 1) = CurrentSheet.Cells(i, 1)
ResultSheet.Cells(k, 2) = CurrentSheet.Cells(i, 14)
k = k + 1
End If
End If
i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below sorts the data in the range A1:A9:

```
Range("A1:A9").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:A9")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

The code was produced using the macro recorder.

Comment: I'm sorry but this did not work, as you can see my code creates another spreadsheet, and I need to figure out how to fit the ascending sort into it.

Answer (score 0):

Just adapt "VBA Proggrammer"'s Code, something like this :

```
'after your code
dim LastRow as long
Dim Rg as Range

with resultsheet
    LastRow = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row 'might be same as k in your code    
    Set Rg= .Range("A1:B" & trim (str(LastRow)))
end With


with Rg.Sort
    with .SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                 order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= xlSortTextAsNumbers
    End With
    .SetRange Range("A1:A9")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Aside from that , the way you declare variables :

```
Dim ReadDays, j, k, LastRow, DaysDiff As Integer
```

is a good example : 
first use Long, as long works faster in VBA.
second , if you write dim a , b as Integer  ,   the variable a is declared as variant, not integer.

correct way :

```
Dim ReadDays as Long, j as Long, k as Long, LastRow as Long, DaysDiff As Long
```

Answer (score 0):

with some help.. this is the final code and it works just fine, thanks for your help:

```
    Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim DueDate, CurrentDate As Date
    Dim ReadDays, j, k, LastRow, DaysDiff As Integer
    Dim ResultSheet, CurrentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SortRange As Range
    Dim SortColumn As Range

    j = 4
    k = 1
    LastRow = 4
    CurrentDate = Date
    ReadDays = InputBox(Prompt:="Set alarm for how many days?", Title:="Alarm Input Box", Default:="Number of days")

    While ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1).Value <> ""
    LastRow = LastRow + 1
    Wend

    Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet()
    Set ResultSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, ActiveSheet())

    While j < LastRow
        If (IsDate(CurrentSheet.Cells(j, 16))) Then
            DueDate = CurrentSheet.Cells(j, 16)
    DaysDiff = DateDiff("d", CurrentDate, DueDate)
    If (DaysDiff <= ReadDays) Then
        ResultSheet.Cells(k, 1) = CurrentSheet.Cells(j, 1)
        ResultSheet.Cells(k, 2) = CurrentSheet.Cells(j, 16)
        k = k + 1
    End If
End If
    j = j + 1
    Wend

    Set SortRange = Range("A1:B" & k)
    Set SortColumn = Range("B1")
    Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 24
    Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 12
    SortRange.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    SortRange.Sort SortColumn, xlAscending

    End Sub
```

this is an example for only one button and you can make the changes for the other one as well..

Credit to Dave :) .. Thanks my friend.